# Youtube error 400 missing prams api v3

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

im sending the following request and i get `error 400 missing params` but when i manually send the request via GET it works fine:

```
try {
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest arg0) throws IOException {}
        }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-myuploads-sample").build();

        YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youtube.channels().list("id,snippet");
        channelRequest.setKey("key");
        //channelRequest.setFields("items/contentDetails,nextPageToken,pageInfo");
        channelRequest.set("channelId", "UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ");
        System.out.println(channelRequest.toString());
        ChannelListResponse channelResult = channelRequest.execute(); //error here
        List<Channel> channelsList = channelResult.getItems();
...
```

but from some reason this works:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=key&channelId=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

more detailed error:

```
    {
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.parameter",
    "location" : "",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "No filter selected.",
    "reason" : "missingRequiredParameter"
  } ],
  "message" : "No filter selected."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong class. It's not a channel, it's a search list according to the url you are mentioned as working.

```
YouTube.Search.List searchRequest = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try it this way:

```
try {
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest arg0) throws IOException {}
        }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-myuploads-sample").build();

        YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youtube.channels().list("id,snippet");
        channelRequest.setFields("items/contentDetails,nextPageToken,pageInfo");
        channelRequest.setId("UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ");

        // probably needed:
        // channelRequest.setMine(true);
        // or
        // channelRequest.setForUsername("userwithaccess");

        System.out.println(channelRequest.toString());
        ChannelListResponse channelResult = channelRequest.execute(); //error here
        List<Channel> channelsList = channelResult.getItems();
```

See this docu: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.Channels.List.html#setId%28java.lang.String%29

Mind the above comments as I'm currently limiting to `...setMine(true); ...`